# JQuery validate Checkbox and Display Feedback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, jquery-validate

I have the following sample code which contains two checkboxes. When the user hits the Submit button I have some JQuery code which determines how many of the checkboxes have been selected.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>


<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {

            var fields = $("input[name='group']").serializeArray();
            if (fields.length == 0) {
                //alert('nothing selected');
                $("myText").html("Selected");
            }
            else {
                //alert(fields.length + " items selected");
                $("myText").html("Not Selected");
            }

        });
    });


</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>

    <form>

    <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="1" />1
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="2" />2

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


    <div id="myText"></div>

    </form>

</div>
```

If no checkboxes have been selected I can create an alert box which informs the user of this, however, ideally, I would like to to avoid using an alert box, and instead, add some feedback text to a DIV I have created.

You can see I am trying to so this with the following code

```
$("myText").html("Selected");
```

But for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone please give me some help with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `#` in `myText` please note `mytext` is `id` and to access id you need to do this

`$("#myText").html("Selected");` rest should work like rocket.

hope this helps the cause `:)`

```
  $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {

            var fields = $("input[name='group']").serializeArray();
            if (fields.length == 0) {
                //alert('nothing selected');
                $("#myText").html("Selected");
            }
            else {
                //alert(fields.length + " items selected");
                $("#myText").html("Not Selected");
            }

        });
    });
```